# How to extract only one element type in JQ from output of CURL in BASH script.?

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am working in simple bash script to get JSON value using CURL and Parse using JQ. Script i am using:

```
 var=$(curl -X GET -k -H "SEC: xxxxxx" 'https://localhost/api/reference_data/sets/malopid?fields=data(value)' | jq '.[]')
 echo $var;
```

Output of curl is:

```
[
  {
    "value": "11.945403842773683082"
  },
  {
    "value": "11.-4947520229339316351"
  },
  {
    "value": "11.-5919145046027777143"
  }
]
```

But i am expecting OP like below:

```
11.945403842773683082
11.945403842773683082
11.945403842773683082
```

Is it possible to do this.? Using this nos i will query another API. Please help me with logic? Please help me on this.

Comment: What's the issue? The API returns a JSON object and you want... a list? Just cycle through the array and put values in another array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting your dummy output is wrong, and you actually want what is listed below:

```
jq '.[].value' -r <<< '[
  {
    "value": "11.945403842773683082"
  },
  {
    "value": "11.-4947520229339316351"
  },
  {
    "value": "11.-5919145046027777143"
  }
]'
```

Output is:

```
11.945403842773683082
11.-4947520229339316351
11.-5919145046027777143
```

> `--raw-output/-r:`
>   With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.